# Haskell Spock IO within GET Route ActionCtxT Error

Tags: haskell, uuid, haskell-spock

I try to return a uuid within a route definition for a web app ([Spock](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Spock) Webserver).

A route is pretty simple to define

```
get("PATH") $ do
 text "Hello World"
```

Now I try to return a uuid via `nextRandom` from the [Data.UUID.V1](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/uuid-1.3.13/docs/Data-UUID-V1.html) module.
The function returns a `IO(Maybe UUID)` value.

So I thought, since I am in IO and work with another IO I have to do bind the value simply with `<-`, like so:

```
get ("id") $ do
    uuid<-nextUUID
    json . pack $ show $ uuid
```

But the compiler says no:

```
Couldn't match type ‘ActionCtxT ctx0 m0’ with ‘IO’
      Expected type: IO b0
        Actual type: ActionCtxT ctx0 m0 b0
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block: json . pack $ show $ uuid
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
        ‘do { uuid <- nextUUID;
              json . pack $ show $ uuid }’
```

Why is it throwing that error?
I could easily create the uuid with a simple print example, but within Spock I don't understand what the ActionCtxT does and why I can't do the uuid IO in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So I thought, since I am in IO and work with another IO

That's the trouble here, when you're routing in Spock, you're not in IO. The error message tells you what context you're really in: `ActionCtxT ctx0 m0`. According to [the docs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Spock-0.10.0.1/docs/Web-Spock-Shared.html#t:SpockActionCtx), that's a [monad transformer stack](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Monad_transformers) that bundles effects and state.

You can "lift" an IO computation into the right type using `liftIO`.

```
get ("id") $ do
    uuid <- liftIO nextUUID
    json . pack $ show $ uuid
```

Comment: That did it.And something new for me to learn. liftIO, Monad Transformer stack ? Well, well, I will get there eventually.
Now the show is returning `Just 03fcbcbe-fbf0-11e6-8001-a8667f260e4c` because uuid is a [Maybe UUID] I suppose. I think I will figure out how to get the actuall value from that somehow and post the full correct result here. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Libbys helpful answer I just added the catch for the `Nothing` of the `Maybe UUID`. Here the full programm:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}


module Main where

import Web.Spock hiding (head)
import Web.Spock.Config

import Data.UUID.V1
import Data.Pool
import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import Database.PostgreSQL.Simple
import Data.Aeson (Value(Null))

import qualified Network.HTTP.Types.Status as Http

type AppAction a = SpockActionCtx () Connection AppSession AppState a
data AppState = EmptyState
data AppSession = EmptySession


main :: IO ()
main =
  do pool<-createPool (connect (ConnectInfo "localhost" 5432 "" "" "envelopes") ) close 1 10 10
     spockCfg <- defaultSpockCfg EmptySession (PCPool pool) EmptyState
     runSpock 8080 (spock spockCfg app)

app :: SpockM Connection AppSession AppState ()
app = do 
    get ("json/id") $ do
      uuid<-liftIO nextUUID
      case uuid of
        Nothing -> do 
          setStatus Http.status500
          json Null
        Just x  -> json $ show x
```